# How to support column for the cat climbing tree

Tags: furniture

Looking for a way to give support for the falling ceiling in the cat climbing tree.
Currently there is a fast fix with what I had around, but that won't last for long.

I Would prefer some sort of jack instead of chopping a piece of wood until it fits correctly.

thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put kitty on a diet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repair in 3 simple steps

- Remove the plastic support
- Replace with a length of wooden dowel, probably don't need to screw it down if you get the length right
- Place kitty on a diet

Comment: I can do the first 2, option 3 is risky :)

Answer (score 3):

screw a block into the side panel so it supports the top. You can also screw the top into that.

Answer (score 3):

For something small like that, where bracing can be on the inside and doesn't have to be pretty, 1/2" or 1" angle brackets should do the trick quite nicely.

Something like this:

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of lowes.com. No endorsement of brand or vendor implied or intended.</sup>

Put one in each corner on the inside. If kitty is getting pudgy, go with a larger bracket.